# Чем boost::signal отличается от std::function

Tags: c++

Чем `boost::signal` отличается от `std::function` ?

Если разговор зайдет про возможности подключить больше одного слота у `boost::signal` - можно переходить к сравнению с массивом `std::function`

Comment: а подписывание-отписывание хотите сами ручками пилить? И если подписывание - это относительно просто, то отписывание часто бывает не таким тривиальным.

Comment: Другими словами - ничем?

Comment: Да, для Вас ничем не отличаются.